# Codeigniter validaton_error() to array

Tags: validation, codeigniter-2

I want to convert the output of the validation_errors() to an array(json object eventually). What I've done so far with the help of other tutorials is this -> I've extended the CI_Form_Validation Library to return the protected array _error_message

```
static function errorToArray()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->form_validation->_error_messages;
}
```

But to no luck have I been able to view what the content inside the array is to even consider passing it to the view. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){

}else{
    $array  =   validation_errors();
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: this just gives me the error text and not the actual array structure which is what I want. I tried using the _error_array from a library and pass that on. Seems to have worked fine like that.